# FB.login() on iOS 6 doesn't return control to scripts with asynchronous execution

Tags: mobile, authentication, ios6, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've created Facebook Bug ID 517124631665353 to ask about this issue, but I'm not sure if it's a bug with Facebook's JS SDK or with the latest version of mobile Safari that comes with iOS 6. This only happens on iPhones and iPads running iOS 6.

Try each of these FB Rell examples:

Plain alert():
http://www.fbrell.com/saved/5224cbd2585cdcd4faefd2de236e577c

```html
<button id="fb-login">Login & Permissions</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('fb-login').onclick = function() {
  var cb = function(response) {
    Log.info('FB.login callback', response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      Log.info('User logged in');
    } else {
      Log.info('User is logged out');
    }
    alert('This fires on Mobile Safari, iOS 6.');
  };
  FB.login(cb, { scope: 'publish_actions' });
};
</script>
```

alert() in setTimeout():
http://www.fbrell.com/saved/9fee23e8553878748f8a3b840e8f0cb5

```html
<button id="fb-login">Login & Permissions</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('fb-login').onclick = function() {
  var cb = function(response) {
    Log.info('FB.login callback', response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      Log.info('User logged in');
    } else {
      Log.info('User is logged out');
    }
    setTimeout(function () {alert('This never fires on Mobile Safari, iOS 6.')}, 0);
  };
  FB.login(cb, { scope: 'publish_actions' });
};
</script>
```

On both iPads and iPhones running iOS 6, the alert() in a setTimeout() does not fire. On iPads, the popup window seems to close itself in all cases, but in iPhones, the popup window does not close, and only sometimes the user is returned to the original page.

We originally saw this problem on www.expertflyer.com/mobile, where we send off an AJAX request once the Facebook login is complete. We found that the code that should execute when that AJAX request returns is never executed. This is shown more simply using the setTimeout() call in the FB Rell example, but the commonality is that asynchronous code is not executed after the Facebook login returns. This was working previously, and we have not made any changes to our code, and this works as expected in earlier versions of iOS and on Android.

Comment: As an experiment, I tried this as a work-around, and it seems to work, as hackish as it is: http://www.fbrell.com/saved/5257b21b47a33775296b26b55b86b607